# Count occurence of @ in validating email address peoplecode

Tags: peoplesoft, peoplecode

I need to validate email address and check if the email address has only one @.

Answer (score 1):

You have several possibilities to solve it:

```
java.util.regex
```

Provide regular expression for email validation and try to match it against provided email.

```
Find(string, within_string [, number])
```

Return value will provide first occurence of search string. Use that value as a 3rd parameter to search for 2nd occurence.

```
Split(string, separator)
```

Test if length of returned array is equal to '2'

Other options:

- search for email validation function within PeopleSoft delivered Application Classes
- SQLExec with match / regex query